# Glassfish logging to multiple .log files

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j

We have Glassfish v2 server and some modules there: EJBs, web-apps, etc...
We need logging from different modules goes to different log files, the same way like Tomcat or other app server allowed to do.

Glassfish forced us to use its own logging system with all logs in single server.log and viewed with admin console.

It *may be a good practice for single application* deployed with glassfish to have all logs in one file, *but not for 10 different apps* working on same server

I tried to [configure log4j in GF](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FaqCongifureLog4J), it helped and I am able to write multiple files, *but* it had one disadvantage - if log4j installed such way it may allow you to write to multiple log files, but *it requeires* server/domain *restart* to modify log level, log file (any log related config in log4 conf)

---

It is possible to use anything in Glassfish that allowes me to:

1. Write logs from different loggers to different .log files? *and*
2. Modify log levels, log appenders etc without server restart (like in tomcat I can just redeploy the .war)??

Comment: If anyone comes across this, the link above is now https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqCongifureLog4J

Answer (score 0):

It seems that default Glassfish logging utility does not allow for this.